# How to ignore a directory in svn status?

Tags: svn, svnignore

I want to ignore a directory or a group of files when I run `svn st`, but I don't want to set the `svn:ignore` property, which means I still want the directory/files to be updated when I run `svn up`.  I just don't want to see the status of that folder. Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could group the files and folders that you'd like to see the status for into a [`changelist`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.changelist.html), and then pass that through to the [`svn status`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html) command using the [`--changelist`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.changelist) option.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `svn:ignore` means that these files won't be shown at `svn st` if they are not already added. If you set `svn:ignore` for a specific file and add this file manually, it is under version control and `svn st` will consider this file.

I don't know what you're exactly doing, but maybe you can "filter" the output of `svn st` and get rid of the unwanted lines afterwards, e.g. using `grep` on the output of `svn st`.